How can I browse a Nextcloud folder structure using Dolphin in Linux?
The Nextcloud docs mention that you can just log in using Dolphin, but this did not work for me.
After getting a warning about absence of authentication, I just get a dialog saying "Unable to connect to server. Please check your settings and try again".
Is there a way to browse my Nextcloud file structure using Dolphin?

I did what this user suggested:

Completely ignore the Dolphin-specific instructions in the Nextcloud docs.

Open a Dolphin window.

Make the path bar editable (†).

Just type webdavs://USER@DOMAIN:443/remote.php/dav/files/USER/. If your user name contains @, change it to %40 in both occurrences in the URL.
If you do not know your username, you can find it by logging into the Nextcloud server via the browser and then going to Settings > Sharing. In "Your Federated Cloud ID", the part before the @ is your username.
Note that if you mistype something, then Dolphin may completely ruin the entire string you entered:

it may switch back to http(s) and somehow promote webdav to be the domain,
it may replace the @ between USER and DOMAIN with %40,
it may replace % signs with %25.


You will be asked for your password AND warned that you are not being asked for your password. I ignored the warning and this worked.

You can drag the folder icon from the editable path bar to your side bar to bookmark the remote Nextcloud folder.


(†) To make the path bar editable:

Settings > Configure Toolbars...
Put the "Editable Location" button in the toolbar. This toggles whether your path bar is editable or not.
It will take up a lot of space, as it is text-only and no icon. Click the button in the toolbar configuration window:

Change Icon... (I chose text-field)
Change Text... > enable "Hide text when toolbar shows text alongside icons"



Application password
The following part of the Nextcloud docs is probably worth taking serious:

When using a third-party WebDAV client (including your operating system’s built-in client), you should use an application password for login rather than your regular password. In addition improved security, this increases performance significantly.

